# Sort a large number of lists with varying length into a smaller number of lists with similar length

Tags: list, sorting

I have 25 lists of unequal length. (Lets call them *Foo* lists) The end result I need is for all elements to be sorted into 4 lists, (Lets call them *Lee* lists) with processing time being unimportant but the final length of the *Lee* lists being as close to equal as possible. Each of the *Foo* lists is indivisible, such that each of the final *Lee* lists must be made up of whole *Foo* lists.

Is there an existing algorithm to deal with this type of sorting? Or must I simply try every possible combination and compare the final lengths?

Comment: Did you mean "such that each of the final *Lee* lists must be made up of whole ***Foo*** lists"?

Comment: I think this is a variant of the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Actually, it's the [multiprocessor scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling) linked from that page.

Comment: @Andreas Yes thank you, OP fixed

Comment: I feel like you could figure this out on your own by sitting down with pen and paper. You could start by using count on the lists so you know how many items in total you have. And then you could start sorting them as needed. This seems very similar to the algorithm to determine exact change in coins from some dollar amount. Only you want to sort into 4 divisions with as little overflow as possible.

Comment: LOL, OP usually refers to the Original Poster. It can refer to Original Post, but that's rarely used. See [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).